# to change the position of pagecontrol

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have used `UIPageContol` in `UIPageViewController` as below:-

uipageviewcontroller class:-

```
class PageControllerViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private var pageViewModel :PageViewModel!

    init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil, withViewModel viewModel:PageViewModel) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: options)

        pageViewModel = viewModel

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let pageControl = UIPageControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


          self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        createPageViewController()

        setupPageControl()

    }

     fileprivate func createPageViewController() {

        if (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers = [firstController]


            self.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

    }

      fileprivate func setupPageControl() {

        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.86, blue: 1, alpha:1.0)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! HomeViewController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! HomeViewController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    fileprivate func getItemController(_ itemIndex: Int) -> HomeViewController? {

        if itemIndex < (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! {



            let homeViewModel :HomeViewModel = QM_HomeViewModel(withmodel:pageViewModel.datafordisplay(objectatindex: itemIndex))
            let ViewController = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil, withViewModel: homeViewModel)


            ViewController.itemIndex = itemIndex
                 return ViewController
        }

        return nil
    }

    // MARK: - Page Indicator

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray! .count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    // MARK: - Additions

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int {

        let pageItemController = self.currentController()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? HomeViewController{
            return controller.itemIndex
        }

        return -1
    }

    func currentController() -> UIViewController? {



        if (self.viewControllers?.count)! > 0 {
            return self.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

  }
```

HomeViewController:-

```
  var itemIndex: Int = 0

     @IBOutlet weak var restaurantname: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var offertype: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var aboutoffer: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dealtype: UILabel!


    private var homeViewModel :QM_HomeViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:QM_HomeViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        homeViewModel  = viewModel
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.restaurantname.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.restaurtantname
        self.offertype.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.offertype
        self.aboutoffer.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.aboutoffer
        self.desc.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.desc
        self.price.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.price
        self.dealtype.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.dealtype


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

[This is the output that i got .Here it works the pageviewcontroller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3OWZ.png)

[when i give  as   self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
 in Homeviewcontroller.I got the output as shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRn9z.png)

So i need the pagecontrol just above this tab bar .How to do

Comment: how to set the loaction of the pagecontrol

Comment: see the updated answer, if you find any issue tell than let me know

Comment: @Dhiru can u help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

To Change the Position

```
 let pageControlWidht = 200 // depending number of dots

let pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl.init(frame:CGRect.init(x: self.view.frame.size.with/2-pageControlWidht, y: self.view.frame.size.hieght-100, width: pageControlWidht, height: 100))
```

For Bringing `UIPageControl` Above .you can use

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.pageControl)
```

and you can track the current page using below code , where `PageContentVC` is the custom `ViewController` Scrolling inside `PageViewController`  you need to store index in each `ViewController`

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    if !completed {
         let pageContentView = previousViewControllers[0] as! PageContentVC;
         self.pageControl.currentPage = pageContentView.pageIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry ,this is not i need .I need to set the location of the pagecontrol

Comment: can you please add screenshot , and demonstrate about your requirment

Comment: here what is pagecontectVc...did i need to create other viewcontroller

Comment: the basic idea is to store the index in each instance of `UIViewController` ,  here `PageContentVC ` is my custom viewController Scrolling inside my `UIPageViewController`. you can use your own Class

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/ this is sample demo.here at the bottom i am using tab  bar of height 49.And i need the uipagecontrol just above the tabbarcontroller.

Comment: ohh,,,that you want , simply use `UIPageControl.init(frame: yourFrame)`

Comment: but i need to set at every phone how to do

Comment: see the updated answer , according the View Size you can calculate the expected position of `UIPageControl`

Comment: if answer helped you ,than you can accept answer . thanks

Comment: Hai ,i don't get the answer.So i have updated the question .please check.And i need according...how to do